# localhost refused to connect on xampp issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have tried to create a session example on Codeigniter php, this is my Sesion_controller.php code.

```
class Session_controller extends CI_Controller {

  public function index() { 
      //loading session library 
      $this->load->library('session');

      //adding data to session 
      $this->session->set_userdata('name','ABC');

      $this->load->view('session_view'); 
  } 

  public function unset_session_data() { 
      //loading session library
      $this->load->library('session');

      //removing session data 
      $this->session->unset_userdata('name'); 
      $this->load->view('session_view'); 
  }         
}
```

This is my Session-view.php code

```
<body> 
  Welcome <?php echo $this->session->userdata('name'); ?>
  <br> 
  <a href = 'http://localhost:8081/codeigniterPhp/index.php/sessionex/unset'>
      Click Here</a> to unset session data. 
</body>
```

Following changes I made in routes.php file

```
$route['sessionex'] = 'Session_Controller';
```

After running this code in my local server, the view page properly run but I get an error in controller page i.e. localhost refused to connect

Comment: Please try to restart your machine and xampp.

Comment: Are you sure the url is `http://localhost:85/CodeIgniter-3.0.1/CodeIgniter3.0.1/index.php/...`?  Should it be `http://localhost/index.php/`

Answer (score 0):

Change your route:

```
$route['sessionex'] = 'Session_Controller/index';
$route['sessionex/unset'] = 'Session_Controller/unset_session_data';
```